# How to make RPC calls over MQTT (Google Iot Core + Mongoose OS)

Tags: mongoose-os

**RPC calls over MQTT**

Hi,
I want to publish a telemetry event by issuing a PUBLISH message(RPC call) to an MQTT topic (${device.id}/rpc)

references:
[RPC over MQTT][(ttps://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/api/rpc/rpc-mqtt.md)
[Publishing telemetry events, Google IoT core](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#publishing_telemetry_events)

I am using below command to call RPC over MQTT

> `mos --port mqtts://mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog:8883/projects/PROJECT_NAME/locations/us-central1/registries/iot-registry/devices/esp8266_C7E6AA --cert-file gcp-esp8266_C7E6AA.pub.pem --key-file gcp-esp8266_C7E6AA.key.pem call Sys.GetInfo`

But I am getting below response

```
$ mos --port mqtts://mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog:8883/projects/PROJECT_NAME/locations/us-central1/registries/iot-registry/devices/esp8266_C7E6AA --cert-file gcp-esp8266_C7E6AA.pub.pem --key-file gcp-esp8266_C7E6AA.key.pem call Sys.GetInfo
Unknown command
Command completed.
```

Is the above command is correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer to save time of people who might face the same problem.

So mos --port command only works form Command line(CMD).

And if you are on windows it require some special formatting that you can find out [here](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose-os/issues/193).

Thanks
Abhi